# Taurus: Console screen failure shows while running Taurus on AWS instance via ssh

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, taurus

I want to monitor the run time execution while running my test at AWS instance via SSH.

I'm able to monitor the test execution in the console of my local machine without facing any issue.

I'm getting `ERROR: Console screen failure:` while running my test at AWS instance via SSH, but my test runs successfully and getting a summary after the test finishes.

Here is the command I run to execute the test on AWS through Taurus :

```
bzt Test.jmx
```

Here is the log:

```
11:18:23 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.14.0
11:18:23 INFO: Starting with configs: ['/tmp/jmx_u1mchoun.json']
11:18:23 INFO: Configuring...
11:18:23 INFO: Artifacts dir: /home/ubuntu/2020-04-06_11-18-23.669977
11:18:23 INFO: Preparing...
11:18:24 WARNING: There is a newer version of Taurus 1.14.1 available, consider upgrading. What's new: http://gettaurus.org/docs/Changelog/
11:18:25 INFO: 2 obsolete CookieManagers are found and fixed
11:18:30 INFO: Starting...
11:18:30 INFO: Waiting for results...
11:18:30 INFO: Waiting for finish...
11:18:31 ERROR: Console screen failure: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
11:18:40 WARNING: Please wait for graceful shutdown...
11:18:40 INFO: Shutting down...
11:18:40 INFO: Post-processing...
11:18:40 INFO: Test duration: 0:00:10
11:18:40 INFO: Samples count: 75, 53.33% failures
11:18:40 INFO: Average times: total 0.080, latency 0.080, connect 0.006
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be the case Taurus fails to initialize its console GUI screen due to your EC2 instance not having GUI.

You can try running your test as:

```
bzt -o modules.console.screen=console Test.jmx
```

If it doesn't help you can just disable the console output like:

```
 bzt -o modules.console.disable=true Test.jmx
```

More information:

- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/)
- [Taurus: Console Reporter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/ConsoleReporter/)